# Pass position to fragment shader in AGAL

Tags: stage3d, agal

I am trying to get into shading with AGAL.
I have set up a full screen quad to be
drawn with shader programs, but I ran
into something unexplainable.

## I have these vertices

```
var vertices:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([

    - 1, - 1, 0, - 1, - 1, 0,
    + 1, - 1, 0, + 1, - 1, 0,
    - 1, + 1, 0, - 1, + 1, 0,
    + 1, + 1, 0, + 1, + 1, 0

]);
```

## This pair of program works

```
vertexShaderAssembler.assemble(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,

    "mov op, va0\n" +
    "mov v0, va1"
);

...

fragmentShaderAssembler.assemble(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT,

    "mov oc, v0"
);
```

## However this does not

```
vertexShaderAssembler.assemble(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,

    "mov op, va0\n" +
    "mov v0, va0"
);

...

fragmentShaderAssembler.assemble(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT,

    "mov oc, v0"
);
```

Any clue on why I have to pass the same values
through va1 and why it does not work when
vertices only have three coordiante?

Answer (score 0):

There are a validation error or wrong indices order, If you don't see any result on the screen. To detect the issue please set enableErrorChecking property to true in context3d object. Stage3d will start to throw validation errors. For any additional questions about Stage3D you can join our Stage3D Group on Facebook and get answers faster.

Comment: Better later than never: There were no validation errors. I have of cource long moved on.